# Using a loop to apply tab1 function from epidisplay

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I have a dataset with 172 variables and I'm trying to generate frequency tables for all of the variables(they're all categorical/character variables). I'm using the tab1 function from the epiDisplay package. I know how to do it for individual variables like I've done in my code below, but is there a way to do it all at once? How would I do this using a loop or lapply?

```
library(epiDisplay)
tab1(data$Race1, sort.group = "decreasing", cum.percent = TRUE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be several ways to do it. This may want to try something like this:

```
library(epiDisplay)
data <- mtcars # as an example data
f_1 <- function(x){tab1(x, sort.group = "decreasing", cum.percent = TRUE)}
lapply(data, f_1)
```

If you do not need graph:

```
f_1 <- function(x){tab1(x, sort.group = "decreasing", cum.percent = TRUE, graph = FALSE)}
lapply(data, f_1)
```

Comment: I'm getting saying "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" when I try to do that.

Comment: I tested it using the `mtcars` data, and worked fine. It could be a data issue (just guessing). If you provide an example data, I can test it on my side.

Comment: Yes, it worked using the second method. Thank you! I have a feeling that the graphs didn't work because I have too many observations in my dataset.